# Member variable access in a C++ Zephyr RTOS Thread

Tags: c++, void-pointers, zephyr-rtos

Let me start by mentioning that I'm aware that my solution is neither thread safe nor clean at all... but that's why I'm writing this question:

I'm trying to implement a thread in a C++ class in Zephyr that can access a member variable. However, this is more of a general C++ question.

Here's my working solution:

- *stepper.h*

```
class Stepper
{
...
private:
    double speed;

    struct k_thread stepper_thread;

    /* Stepper thread entry */
    static void stepper_thread_entry(void *, void *, void *);

    /* Stepper thread function */
    void stepper_thread_function(auto& desired_speed);
};
```

- *stepper.cpp*

```
Stepper::Stepper(void) : speed(0)
{
k_tid_t stepper_thread_tid = k_thread_create(&stepper_thread,    
                                  stepper_thread_stack_area,
                                  K_THREAD_STACK_SIZEOF(stepper_thread_stack_area),                                
                                  Stepper::stepper_thread_entry, 
                                  this, NULL, NULL,
                                  STEPPER_THREAD_PRIORITY, 0, K_MSEC(10));

}

...

void Stepper::stepper_thread_entry(void *instance, void *, void *)
{
    auto thead_instance = reinterpret_cast<Stepper *>(instance);
    thead_instance->stepper_thread_function(thead_instance->speed);
}

void Stepper::stepper_thread_function(double& desired_speed)
{
    // access desired_speed
    ...
}
```

I'm not especially happy with the implementation in `Stepper::stepper_thread_entry`, but it was the only way i found to work around the fact that the `K_THREAD_STACK_SIZEOF` macro requires a static function.

Is there a cleaner way to implement this?

Thanks in advance :)

edit: fixed formatting erros

Comment: What's `current_speed` and how, if at all, is it related to `speed`?

Comment: This pattern is a pretty standard, common way to integrate with C-style libraries from C++. Those intermediate static functions are sometimes referred to as [trampolines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing))

Comment: By the way, I don't see the point of `auto& desired_speed` parameter to `stepper_thread_function`. It already has access to `speed` member variable - that was the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik 1. thanks for your reply, the `current_speed` is a formatting typo which of course should be `speed`.
2. I was also expecting the `stepper_thread_function` to have access to the member variable. However, i got some kernel errors on my ESP32 during runtime when I tried it.